# remote roslaunch log files location

Tags: logging, remote-access, ros

I am running ROS Indigo in an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

When launching a remote roslaunch on a robot as the following (some ommited parts are not relevant to the question) :

```
<launch>
<machine name="$(arg name)" address="$(arg robot_ip)" env-loader="~/catkin_ws/src/setup_env.bash" 
    user="wifibot" password="****" timeout="10.0" default="never"/>

<node machine="$(arg name)" name="$(arg name)" pkg="wifibot" type="wifibot_controller" output="log">
    <param name="id" value="$(arg id)" />
    <param name="vl" value="$(arg vl)" />
    <param name="va" value="$(arg va)" />
    <param name="name" value="$(arg name)" />
</node> 
<launch/>
```

everything works Ok, but when it comes to end, **I couldn't find the remote roslaunch log files in both .ros/log/ folders**.

I searched both in my local and remote machines with no clues.

Does someone have a hint ?

Cheers,

Comment: Could You please try executing `roslaunch-logs` on the remote machine? It supposed to return the log directory.

Comment: It was the usual .ros/log/ and nothing was in there ...

Comment: Hmmm. The thing is... that the *.launch file is parsed in local machine and only later executed in the remote one. I guess, there might be bug that it tries to fill the log on `$ROS_HOME/log` which is non-existent on remote machine. Could You please try setting ROS_HOME to /tmp or something which is on remote machine as well?